# Delete a user in database with name user1;

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a user in the database with the username "USER1;" including the semicolon.
How to remove this user?
When I tried with

```
SQL> drop user user1; cascade;
drop user user1; cascade
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

How to remove this user then?

Note: Database Oracle 11g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enclose the name in double quotes if it contains characters [that aren't allowed in non-quoted names](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm):

```
drop user "USER1;" cascade;
```

The user must have been created in the same way. Note that Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers (including, by implication, user names). Trying to refer to objects in that user's schema would have been a pain.